# Adding raw query parameters via Criteria API

Tags: solr, spring-data-solr

I could not find an answer to this. I found the previous similar question unanswered. I'd like to use Spring data solr for queries. But `@Query` is insufficient for my needs. As I understood, whatever you give here becomes a `q` parameter to `select' handler of solr.

In my case I need to add more parameters for example `sfield` for a spatial search. If `@Query` wont cut it, I am ready to write a custom repository implementation by autowiring `SolrTemplate`, But then the `Criteria` API does not seem to let me add a raw query parameter either.

Any help/points will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Every possible opportunity of extending SolrTemplate or QueryParser is closed as most of these points are final (In my opinon thats bad design for a project like data solr where you cannot always implement every functionality). I  guess will just have to directly code using SolrServer and SolrQuery and handle all the paging myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around it by creating a `QueryParser` decorator that adds the required parameters to a parsed solr query. The `QueryParser` was registered using `solrTemplate.registerQueryParser()`.

Note however that I had to do a really nasty hack to get this working, since all queries that are sent to `solrTemplate.queryForPage` are wrapped by a static package protected inner class in QueryBase. So my registration code above had to be in a package `org.springframework.data.solr.core`